# Card66 plugin: ShortCode dialog is blank when add product

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Cart66 Lite version 1.5.0.2, wordpress 3.4.2. When I try to add new a product, I want to insert a short code to my editor. I click Cart66 short code link on top Editor. The blank dialog is showed with no configuration.

The same issue in follow article: http://docs.cart66.com/knowledgebase/custom-post-types/

But I don't use Post Type plugin in my case.

Could anyone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answer for myself. 
Post Type plugin is current exist from Wordpress 3.0. So, the reference article is correct.
But, add_filter() is unknow in this case. To fix it, We should move required /plugin.php before required /function.php in wp-setting.xml.